# Automatic template deduction for function pointers

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

In the following code

```cpp
template<class T> void f(T);
int main(){
    f(3);
    return 0;
}
```

the template argument `int` for deduces automatically, as usual.

But in

```
template<class T> void f(T);
template<class T> void (*p)(T) = f<T>;

int main(){
    p(3);
    return 0;
}
```

the compiler (clang++) insists that `p(3)` needs a template parameter. Why?

Besides, if I put the line `template<class T> void (*p)(T) = f<T>;` in a header to be included by several files, will that cause problems?

Comment: Because there's no overload resolution happening here. If you automatically want to use the correct function pointer, you need a helper function, e.g. `template<class T> void CallP(T arg){ p<T>(std::move(arg)); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template argument deduction works with function templates and and with CTAD from C++17. Writing a wrapper is trivial for your example.

```
template<class T> void f(T);
template<class T> void (*p)(T) = f<T>;


template<typename T> void Wrapper(T&& t)
{
    p<T>(std::forward<T>(t));
}

int main(){
    Wrapper(3);
}
```

Comment: Interesting that template deduction works for functions and classes, but not function pointers. Anyway, thank you!